# How can I get integer in Math.pow(10, 10000000)

Tags: javascript, math, integer, pow

I always get infinity from:

```js
let power = Math.pow(2, 10000000);
console.log(power); //Infinity
```

So, can I get integer from this?
Maybe I don't understand this task https://www.codewars.com/kata/5511b2f550906349a70004e1/train/javascript? Who knows, show me how to decide that?

Comment: The largest Integer in Javascript is (2^53)-1. Your result is too big for a single variable.

Comment: The result will be significantly larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` where arithmetics will fail. Why do you need this so large number?

Comment: are you trying this for just fun ? or any real scenario ? this number normally wont exists in real scenarios.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says you need 3,010,300 digits to store the result.

Comment: This is written in this task https://www.codewars.com/kata/5511b2f550906349a70004e1/train/javascript . I need to get string result, but number.

Comment: There is a NodeJs module to store big integers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer, but if you really need it you can try mimicking the code from (BigInteger.prototype.pow):
https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link that you give asks for the *last digit* of the number. In order to find such a thing, it would be insane to compute an extremely large number (which might exceed the storage capacity of the known universe to write down (*)) just to find the final digit. Work mod 10.

Two observations:

```
1) n^e % 10 === d^e % 10 // d = last digit of n
2) If e = 10q+r then n^e % 10 === (n^10)^q * n^d %10
```

This allows us to write:

```
const lastDigit = function(str1, str2){
  //in the following helper function d is an integer and exp a string
  const lastDigitHelper = function(d,exp){
    if(exp.length === 1){
      let e = parseInt(exp);
      return Math.pow(d,e) % 10;
    } else {
      let r = parseInt(exp.slice(-1));
      let q = exp.slice(0,-1);
      return lastDigitHelper(Math.pow(d,10) % 10,q) * Math.pow(d,r) % 10;
    }
  }

  let d = parseInt(str1.slice(-1));
  return lastDigitHelper(d,str2);
}
```

This passes all of the tests, but isn't as efficient as it could be. The recursive helper function could be replaced by a loop.

(*) For fun: one of the test cases was to compute the last digit of

```
1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376 ^ 2037035976334486086268445688409378161051468393665936250636140449354381299763336706183397376
```

If written in base 2, this number would be approximately 4.07 x 10^92 bits long. Since there are fewer than that many [atoms in the universe](https://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/), the number is much too large to store, not to mention too time consuming to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a maximum safe integer:

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
9007199254740991
```

safe = the ability to represent integers exactly and to correctly compare them

In your case, the number is greater:

```
Math.pow(2, 10000000) >= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
true
```

Or not smaller:

```
Math.pow(2, 10000000) <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
false
```

You can use an arbitrary size integer library like [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) to work with larger integers